# Sublime text 3 log location

Tags: sublimetext3

Title says it all.  Searched around on SO before asking but couldn't find one that has specifically asked about the general error log file for sublime.

I know errors and events are output in the console but it appears the console refreshes on restart, so this doesn't help as in my situation ST3 hangs non-deterministically.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that is exposed, at least not much in-depth.  If you want that functionality, you may want to get the [SublimeLog](https://github.com/yrammos/SublimeLog) package.

However, even that package will clear out the logs on each start.  Fortunately, the source code is available - so you could probably override this behavior fairly easily.

> Sublime Text 2 and 3 provide a console (accessible via Control-`) for
>   interaction with their Python-based innards and plug-in architecture.
>   **This plug-in logs the console contents into a plain-text file
>   ornamented with logger activation/deactivation timestamps.**
>
> *The log is erased and recreated each time Sublime Text is launched.*

*Emphasis added*